# How do I rearrange/sort/organize objects within the same level in the outliner (without collections/parenting)

Tags: outliner

Is there a way to drag and drop objects within the outliner? What I'm looking for is similar to middle click dragging like in Maya, or left click dragging layers around Photoshop's layer stack.

I tried unticking alphabetical sort, but that forces it to be arranged by order in which they are added.

Comment: Hello :). I'm afraid it's not possible currently. But it seems to be in [development](https://developer.blender.org/T68502).

Comment: Aw damn :( well hopefully this gets implemented soon.

Answer (score 0):

That is what collections are for. You Organize things under collections. There are some good tutorials for that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, as of version 3.5 Blender can't (yet) do a custom object/bone sorting in the outliner.